# Is it possible to create a secret_id to use it in an approle automatically without the help of an administrator or kubernetes when using vault?

Tags: node.js, token, hashicorp-vault, app-secret

Recently searching the internet I found a good alternative to manage the secrets of my application created in node js with the help of hashicorp vault. I have investigated how it works and among the possible ways that this tool has to enter I found approle, which I consider an adequate form of authentication through my application. This form of authentication requires a role_id and a secret_id. The latter, as I see in the examples of the official vault page, needs an entity for its creation and then passes it to the application and in this way the application can receive the token to enter the vault. Currently I have this code in node js that receives a token wrapped with the secret_id to achieve access to the secrets with the role of the application:

```
//get the wrap token from passed in parameter
var wrap_token = process.argv[2];

if(!wrap_token){
    console.error("No wrap token, enter token as argument");
    process.exit();
}
 
var options = {
    apiVersion: 'v1', // default
    endpoint: 'http://127.0.0.1:8200',
    token: wrap_token //wrap token
  };

console.log("Token being used " + process.argv[2]);

// get new instance of the client
var vault = require("node-vault")(options);

//role that the app is using
const roleId = '27f8905d-ec50-26ec-b2da-69dacf44b5b8';

//using the wrap token to unwrap and get the secret
vault.unwrap().then((result) => {

  var secretId = result.data.secret_id;
  console.log("Your secret id is " + result.data.secret_id);

  //login with approleLogin
  vault.approleLogin({ role_id: roleId, secret_id: secretId }).then((login_result) => {       
    var client_token = login_result.auth.client_token;
    console.log("Using client token to login " + client_token);
    var client_options = {
        apiVersion: 'v1', // default
        endpoint: 'http://127.0.0.1:8200',
        token: client_token //client token
    };

    var client_vault = require("node-vault")(client_options);

    client_vault.read('secret/weatherapp/config').then((read_result) => {
        console.log(read_result);
    });
  });
}).catch(console.error);
```

The problem is that I plan to upload the application in the cloud using docker and the idea is that the process of obtaining the secrets is automatic so I would like to know if when creating a token that lasts long enough that you only have the possibility of obtaining the secret_id of a role and saving it as environment variable is appropriate in this case or if there is any other alternative that can help me in automating this case.

**Note: I don't plan to deploy in aws in this case.**